# Is there any world-wide real time catastrophe information system?

Tags: tool-request, real-time, geohazard

Disasters happens, in this situations information is everything.

Is there any information system that works worldwide and would:

- Notify the possible victims that the something is coming (in cases it is possible to figure out before)
- Provide useful information during/after the catastrophe:

  - water sources in case of fire/lack of water
  - missing person reports
  - damaged area information
  - where to get help, what help is on the way
  - etc...

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Alerting_Protocol

Comment: [This](http://www.fcc.gov/encyclopedia/emergency-alert-system-nationwide-test) is an interesting project from US, but I do not want to limit to their ideas

Comment: [Google's people finder](http://google.org/personfinder/global/home.html) might be something you'd be interested in.

Comment: @johnthexiii yup... it is actually some of the things that I have in mind when I asked the question, but I choose to wait for the community answers because you guys could have better answers them mine, and I just know had some ideas not a decent answer

Comment: btw [this](http://www.oosa.unvienna.org/oosa/en/sapidx.html) is other idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no system in use that would alert people before the disaster.

To all the other questions, quite a lot of countries have adopted Sahana Eden, that does all the tasks related to the Management of the Disaster, including all the information you have putted there and a lot more...

It has been deployed in large disaster scenarios and it is "as good as it gets", also it complies with UN Standards!

Comment: Could you please add more information about the Sahana Eden project as well as a link? Sounds interesting!

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct to say that you can't alert before a disaster. In Japan they have warning systems for earthquakes. Since an these take a matter of seconds to propagate across the country, they are able to make a message appear immediately on everyone's mobile phones allowing them to get under a table or out of a building. In addition, their bullet trains to stop dead.

Answer (score 4):

The two most promising open source solutions for disaster management seem to be [**Sahana Eden**](http://eden.sahanafoundation.org/) and [**Ushahidi**](http://ushahidi.com/products/ushahidi-platform). To quote from their respective websites:

*Sahana Eden*:

> Sahana Eden is an Open Source Humanitarian Platform which can be used to provide solutions for Disaster Management, Development, and Environmental Management sectors.

*Ushahidi Platform:*

> You can use the *Ushahidi Platform* for information collection, visualization and interactive mapping.

According to [this overview article on Sahana Eden](http://live.osgeo.org/en/overview/sahana_overview.html), the two tools can even be integrated:

> Sahana Eden is also able to integrate with other solutions and can provide a management/ticketing interface around crowd-sourced data - such as that collected in the Ushahidi incident mapping application.

Answer (score 3):

The [Global Disaster Alert and Coordination System](http://www.gdacs.org/) should address the alert part.

> GDACS is a cooperation framework between the United Nations, the
>   European Commission and disaster managers worldwide to improve alerts,
>   information exchange and coordination in the first phase after major
>   sudden-onset disasters.

As for the coordination of relief etc, I don't think there's a worldwide system for that. The closest I can think of would be the [UN OCHA humanitarian response sites](https://www.humanitarianresponse.info/).